# Change GridView Item DataTemplate based on seperate ViewModel Property in WinRT

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, datatemplate

What I am attempting to do is have a collection of items shown in a GridView control and have the size of these items change based on a command executed by a separate button.

For example, having a row of buttons across the top reading “Small”, “Medium” and “Large” and having the items in the GridView respond to the relevant command by displaying its items in the relevant state.

I have the gridview declared like so

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}"
```

With Squares being an observable collection of Square objects that have a Title and a Fill property.

At first I went down the DataTemplateSelector route by declaring the following data templates in the Resources section of the page.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SquareSmallTemplate">
        <Grid Height="100" Width="100">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SquareMediumTemplate">
        <Grid Height="150" Width="150">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SquareLargeTemplate">
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The idea being that the grid’s height and width properties are different for the relevant template. I declared the following data templates in the selector

```
public DataTemplate SmallTemplate { get; set; }
public DataTemplate MediumTemplate { get; set; }
public DataTemplate LargeTemplate { get; set; }
```

And in the SelecteTemplateCore method I just returned the relevant template

```
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string value = item as string;

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value == "Small")
                return SmallTemplate;
            else if (value == "Medium")
                return MediumTemplate;
            else if (value == "Large")
                return LargeTemplate;
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
        }            
    }
```

However, with this method (and, by design of the DataTemplateSelector) the object being passed in is the item in the collection (the Square).

This is fine if I wanted each item to have a different appearance or something, but what I need is the template to change based on another property on the view model.

For this, I have the following

```
public string State {get; set;}
```

and this is set to “Small”, “Medium, or “Large based on a separate row of three buttons that execute a command that sets this property to the relevant value.

How do I relate the State property to changing to the relevant DataTemplate?

Another route I tried was to have a single Data template that used the VSM to animate the Height/Width properties in the relevant states. However I could not get the relevant animation to execute when the State changed.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, I'm not sure which would be best.  In any case, you'll need 1) a trigger, and 2) the action to update the template.  I am leaning towards using [PropertyChangedTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.propertychangedtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) along with an [`InvokeCommandAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.invokecommandaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

```
<GridView x:Name="grid">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding State}">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=UpdateTemplateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding State}" />
        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<GridView>
```

(Here the "AncestorType" would just be the root of the view, so please change "UserControl" as needed.)

Then in the view, you would have an `ICommand` that updates the template:

```
 UpdateTemplateCommand = new DelegateCommand(state => {
     switch ((string)state)
     {
         default:
         case "Small" : grid.ItemTemplate = "SquareSmallTemplate"; break;
         case "Medium" : grid.ItemTemplate = "SquareMediumTemplate"; break;
         case "Large" : grid.ItemTemplate = "SquareLargeTemplate"; break;
     }
 });
```

IDK ... after writing this out it seems a bit convoluted.  Maybe you'd find it preferable to add a `CurrentDataTemplate` property to the view-model, and assign it by creating `DataTemplate`s from strings using `XamlReader`.

Comment: this is a good approach but AncestorType is not supported in WinRT apps